# ¿Hacer contador cada vez que se usa un condicional IF - ELSE?

Tags: javascript

Necesito hacer un simple contador para un condicional IF-ELSE, la duda es sencilla: mi código recorre los números de 100 al 999 y determina cuáles son de composición creciente, decreciente y mixto.

Ejemplo:

```
creciente=159  
decreciente=851  
mixto=253
```

Para saber esta relación utilizo un IF-ELSE, lo que tengo que realizar es un contador que cada vez que se utiliza un `if` aumente, la idea es hacer un acumulador cada vez que se cumpla una condición específica, para luego usar ese acumulador y sacar un porcentaje de los números crecientes decrecientes y mixtos.

```js
function DeterminaNumeros(numero) {
  var num = numero.toString()
  var a = num.split(''); // separa los digitos y los convierte en matriz
  for (x = 0; x < a.length; x++) {
  }
  if (x == 3) {
    if (a[0] >= a[1] && a[1] >= a[2]) {
      //----------------------------------------------
      var acum3 = 1;
      var suma = 0;
      var valor = 0;
      while (acum3 <= 5) {
        valor = parseInt(valor);
        suma = suma + valor;
        acum3 = acum3 + 1;
      }

      //document.write('decreciente ');
      //-------------------------------------------------
    } else {
      if (a[0] <= a[1] && a[1] <= a[2]) {
        document.write('creciente ');

      } else {
        var acum3 = 0;
        document.write('Numero Mixto ');
      }
    }

  }
}

N = 99;
do {
  N = N + 1;
  var resultado = DeterminaNumeros(N);
  document.write(resultado + '<br>');
  document.write(N);
} while (N < 1001);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cogiendo tu código y modificándolo, te propongo el siguiente:

```
function DeterminaNumeros(numero) {
    var num = numero.toString()
    var a = num.split(''); // separa los digitos y los convierte en matriz
    if (a.length == 3) {
        if (a[0] >= a[1] && a[1] >= a[2]) {      
            decrecientes++;
            return "decreciente";
        } else {
            if (a[0] <= a[1] && a[1] <= a[2]) {
                crecientes++;
                return "creciente";
            } else {
                mixtos++;
                return "mixto";
            }
        }
    }
}

var crecientes=0;
var decrecientes=0;
var mixtos=0;

var totalNumeros=0;
for(var i=100;i<=999;i++){
    totalNumeros++;
    var resultado = DeterminaNumeros(i);
    //document.write(N +" es " + resultado +"<br>");
}
document.write(totalNumeros + " números<br>");
document.write(crecientes + " son crecientes ("+ crecientes*100/totalNumeros +"%)<br>");
document.write(decrecientes + " son decrecientes ("+ decrecientes*100/totalNumeros +"%)<br>");
document.write(mixtos + " son mixtos ("+ mixtos*100/totalNumeros +"%)<br>");
```

He eliminado el bucle for que utilizabas para comprobar la longitud de los números ya que no tenía sentido cuando ya lo tienes con `a.length`

He eliminado esas variables como valor, suma y acum3 porque no acabo de ver para qué las quieres si finalmente no las usas para nada.

He cambiado el bucle Do-While por un bucle for por eficiencia y sencillez.

He añadido que la función retorne el tipo de número.

Por último he añadido al final el calculo de los porcentajes.

Los resultados son:

900 números
156 son crecientes (17.333333333333332%)
219 son decrecientes (24.333333333333332%)
525 son mixtos (58.333333333333336%)

Espero que sea lo que necesitabas.

En cuanto a las condiciones de los if, en caso de que sean números con las 3 cifras iguales, podrían considerarse crecientes o decrecientes indistintamente, aunque ahora mismo siempre se considerarán como decrecientes ya que es el primer if.

Comment: Buena Solucion Amigo la verdad me resolvio la problematca muchas gracias

Comment: @YaderYepez me alegro de que te fuese de utilidad. Si no te importa, marca la respuesta como solución. Un saludo.

Comment: si te ha servido marca la respuesta como aceptada

Answer (score 2):

Si te he entendido bien quieres obtener los números estrictamente crecientes, los decrecientes y mixtos y calcular el porcentaje de cada uno de ellos. En ese caso no necesitas complicarte tanto. Te dejo dos soluciones. Una sin utilizar ES6 y otra con ES6

**Sin ES6**

```js
var sumCrec = 0;
var sumDec = 0;
var sumMixto = 0;
function DeterminaNumeros(numero){
        var num=numero.toString()
        var a=num.split(''); // separa los digitos y los convierte en matriz     
            if (a[0]>=a[1] && a[1]>=a[2]) { 
              sumDec++;
            }else{
              if (a[0]<=a[1] && a[1]<=a[2]) {
                sumCrec++;
              }else{
                sumMixto++;
              }
    }
}
var N=100;
var aux = N;
    do{        
        DeterminaNumeros(aux);  
  aux++;  
    }while(aux<1001);

 document.write('Crecientes: ' + sumCrec + '/' + (aux-1-N) + '(' + Number(sumCrec/(aux-1-N) *100) +'%)'+'<br>');
 document.write('Decrecientes: ' + sumDec + '/' + (aux-1-N) + '(' + Number(sumDec/(aux-1-N) *100) +'%)'+'<br>');
 document.write('Mixtos: ' + sumMixto + '/' + (aux-1-N) + '(' + Number(sumMixto/(aux-1-N) *100) +'%)'+'<br>');
 document.write('<hr/>');
```

```js
var sumCrec = 0;
var sumDec = 0;
var sumMixto = 0;
var Ninic=100;
var N=1001;
var arrCrec = [];
var arrDecrec = [];
var arrMixto = [];

//Esta es una forma de generar un array de enteros añadiendo el símbolo iterator al prototype del tipo Number (utilizamos generadores)
Number.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function*(){
  for(let i=Ninic;i<this;i++){
     yield i;    
  }
 }

determinaNumerosES6(N); 

 function determinaNumerosES6(numero){
    //Obtenemos el array de enteros desde la Ninic hasta el número indicado
  let arr = [...numero];
    //Por cada valor comprobamos cómo está ordenado
    arr.forEach((val)=>{
    howIsSorted(val.toString());
  });
  
  document.write('Crecientes: ' + sumCrec + '/' + (N-1-Ninic) + '(' + Number(sumCrec/(N-1-Ninic) *100) +'%)'+'<br>');
    document.write(arrCrec + '<br/>');
    document.write('<hr/>');
  document.write('Decrecientes: ' + sumDec + '/' + (N-1-Ninic) + '(' + Number(sumDec/(N-1-Ninic) *100) +'%)'+'<br>');
    document.write(arrDecrec + '<br/>');
    document.write('<hr/>');
  document.write('Mixtos: ' + sumMixto + '/' + (N-1-Ninic) + '(' + Number(sumMixto/(N-1-Ninic) *100) +'%)'+'<br>');
    document.write(arrMixto + '<br/>');
  document.write('<hr/>');
 }

function howIsSorted(num){
  let aux = num.split('');
  //Ascendentes --> Sumamos y guardamos en array (por si queremos ver los valores que cumplen la condición)
  if(isAscending(aux)){
    sumCrec++;
    arrCrec.push(num);
  }
  else if(isDescending(aux)){
    sumDec++;
    arrDecrec.push(num);
  }
  else{
    sumMixto++;
    arrMixto.push(num);
  }
}

//Hacemos una copia del array de entrada con slice desde el índice 1. A continuación con map creamos un nuevo array cuyos valores serán el resultado de la función de comprobación (e>=a[i]). Así obtendremos un array con [true, true, false, o lo que sea, según se cumpla la función o no). Por último, con every devolvemos true o false si todos los elementos del array son iguales en este caso (todo trues querrá decir que está ordenado de forma ascendente.
function isAscending(a){ 
return a.slice(1)
    .map((e,i) => e >= a[i])
    .every(x => x);
}
              
//Lo mismo que isAscending pero con orden descendiente
function isDescending(a){
 return a.slice(1)
    .map((e,i) => e <= a[i])
    .every(x => x);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Lo que se me ocurre es declarar los contadores fuera le la funcion DeterminarNumeros volviendolos globales y despues colocar un incremento de estos dentro de cada if, quedando de la siguiente manera.

```js
var countCreciente = 0;
var countDecreciente = 0;
var countMixto = 0;
function DeterminaNumeros(numero) {
      
  var num = numero.toString()
  var a = num.split(''); // separa los digitos y los convierte en matriz
  for (x = 0; x < a.length; x++) {
  }//for (x = 0; x < a.length; x++)
  if (x == 3) {
    if (a[0] >= a[1] && a[1] >= a[2]) {
      //----------------------------------------------
      var acum3 = 1;
      var suma = 0;
      var valor = 0;
      while (acum3 <= 5) {
        valor = parseInt(valor);
        suma = suma + valor;
        acum3 = acum3 + 1;
      }//while (acum3 <= 5)
      countDecreciente++;
      //document.write('decreciente ');
      //-------------------------------------------------
    } else {
      if (a[0] <= a[1] && a[1] <= a[2]) {
        document.write('creciente ');
        countCreciente++;
      } else {
        var acum3 = 0;
        countMixto++;
        document.write('Numero Mixto ');
      }//else
    }//else

  }//if (x == 3)
}//DeterminaNumeros


N = 99;
do {
  N = N + 1;
  var resultado = DeterminaNumeros(N);
  document.write(resultado + '<br>');
  document.write(N);
} while (N < 1001);
document.write('<br>Total crecientes: ' + countCreciente + '<br>');
document.write('Total decrecientes: ' + countDecreciente + '<br>');
document.write('Total mixtos: ' + countMixto + '<br>');
```

Comment: Al efectuar esto que indicas, crear variable globales que no se limpian en memoria, pudiendo a crear problemas de memoria en usuarios. Si a futuro no se precisa del uso de esas variables no se deben crear globales, si no en la fn

Comment: pero si declara los contadores dentro de la función no va a funcionar, porque desde fuera no puede acceder a las variables dentro de la función y en cada llamada a la función los contadores vuelven a tener el valor inicial. Tiene que declararlas fuera y que la función las incremente

Comment: Añade el código externo a la fn en otra fn y llamas a esa función consiguiendo así re-utilización de código y no mantener en memoria datos innecesarios :)